# Xcode Storyboard recovery

Tags: ios, storyboard, ipa

So I lost my source storyboard file. But I still had the `.ipa` that I released.
 
So I used crunch to extract my storyboard. However, it is the `Main.storyboardc` version and renaming it to `Main.storyboard` turned it into a folder with multiple .nib files.

Is there anyway I can turn these files into a storyboard or can I use these instead?

Comment: If it popped up that means you can find it in your project folder. Just look in /projectName/projectName/Base.lproj. The storyboard is there. You can drag it into Xcode and its as good as new.

Comment: @Rajesh Not this time, this particular storyboard is long gone.

Comment: As a advice for future always use version control system: git, svn, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the .nib files but all the logic of the storyboard is lost.

And no you can't convert this into a storyboard file as you don't have the storyboard logic recovered.
Imagine if any one can extract interface/code from a compiled application.

But you can create a new storyboard, opening the nib files and copying the interface inside your new storyboard. You only have to recreate the segues, and relink the outlets.

You can also extract the original nibs from the .ipa file :

1. Rename the MyApp.ipa to MyApp.zip
2. Extract it
3. Inside the extracted folder right click the MyApp.app and press "Show package contents"
4. Here you will have all the resources, including the nib files.

Comment: When I try to open one of the nibs with xcode I get the message: "Try opening the source document instead of the compiled nib.". How should I go about using them?

Comment: Added the way to extract the nibs from .ipa

Comment: I have the .storyboardc and the nib files inside it. But what is the process for importing them to xcode? I've never used .nib files before

Comment: Use my how to to extract them, then import them inside Xcode. It's easy just drag&drop the file like any other.

If you never used nibs, google it...